# More than one ssh-agent

Tags: openssh, ssh-agent, lubuntu

I've recently installed Lubuntu and openssh-server. I can't understand why do I have two ssh-agent process now running in my computer:

```
user1@machine:~$ ps -auwxxx | grep ssh
root     863  0.0  0.1  10004  5128 ?        Ss   16:04   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
user1   1081  0.0  0.0   4608   208 ?        Ss   16:05   0:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session /usr/bin/im-launch /usr/bin/lxsession -s Lubuntu -e LXDE
user1   1164  0.0  0.0   4608   204 ?        Ss   16:05   0:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent -s
user1   9660  0.0  0.0   6332   812 pts/0    S+   19:11   0:00 grep --color=auto ssh
```

What's that behaviour about?

Comment: I think seeing the PPID would be quite self-explanatory:  `ps -ef|grep ssh`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same processes, in running mode, one have PPID 1 (-s) and the other have `lxsession` as PPID.

When I modify `/usr/bin/ssh-agent` to know what is the launcher for `ssh-agent -s` and I got `lightdm --session-child 12 19`